# What's the right method to override in an IBDesignable view so it shows up in the Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I am building some **IBDesignable** views (by code) and I want them to be available in the Interface Builder with the custom changes I’m doing in the `*.swift` view class. In that case, what is the best method to override in my custom view? And Why?

- `layoutSubviews()`
- `drawRect(rect: CGRect)`
- `init(frame: CGRect)`
- or `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`: in this case, I'd probably need to call my custom view changes from more than one method

Answer (score 0):

Override function below for live:

```
override open func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
   //do all your stuff here
}
```

`prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` only needs to be implemented if you need special design appearance in InterfaceBuilder

Comment: Ok  @AtulParmar, but this way the views would be rendered only in the Interface Builder and not when I run the code